# Laravel custom pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to link a third table to two others. So I tried to use a custom pivot table without success.

I have three tables :

- Apartment (I call it "Lot")
- Floor (I call it "Etage)
- Surface (I call it "Fraction")

My relationship :

- Lot has many Etage (duplex apartment)
- Lot has many Fraction
- Etage has many Lot
- Etage has many Fraction
- Fraction has one Etage
- Fraction has one Lot

And my models right now :

```
class Lot extends Model
{
    public function etages(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
    }

    public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
    if ($parent instanceof Event) {
        return new EtageLot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}

class Etage extends Model
{
    public function lots()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
    }

    public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof User) {
            return new EtageLot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
     }
}

class EtageLot extends Pivot
{

    protected $table = 'etage_lot';

    public function lot(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
    }

    public function etage(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
    }

    public function fractions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Fraction','etage_lot_id');
    }
}

class Fraction extends Model
{

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Type');
    }

    public function EtageLot(){
        return $this->belongsTo('etage_lot','etage_lot_id');
    }

}
```

But each time I try to open a page on my site that use one of these models, I have this error :

> Declaration of App\Models\Copro\Lot::newPivot(App\Models\Copro\Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newPivot(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists, $using = NULL)

I don't find something usefull to help me. I tried to rewrite my tables but it doesn't work better.

Someone know why I have this error and how to use this pivot table to get all fractions for an apartment for example ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this, without using Pivot model.

```
class Lot extends Model
{
    public function etageLots(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot');
    }

    public function fractions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Copro\Fraction','App\Models\Copro\EtageLot', 'etage_id', 'etage_lot_id');
    }
}

class Etage extends Model
{
    public function lotEtages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot');
    }

}

class EtageLot extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'etage_lot';

    public function lot(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Lot');
    }

    public function etage(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Etage');
    }

    public function fractions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Fraction','etage_lot_id');
    }
}

class Fraction extends Model
{

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Type');
    }

    public function EtageLot(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\EtageLot','etage_lot_id');
    }

}
```

**Fetch Data**

```
$apartment = Lot::with('etageLots','etageLots.etage', 'fractions')->first();
dd($apartment->fractions);
foreach($apartment->etageLots as $etageLot){
    dd($etageLot->etage);
}
```

**All apartment with fraction counts**

```
$apartments = Lot::with('etageLots','etageLots.etage', 'fractions')->withCount('fractions')->get();

foreach($apartments as $apartment){
    dd($apartment->fractions_count);
    dd($apartment->fractions); //direct fractions for each apartment
    foreach($apartment->etageLots as $etageLot){
        dd($etageLot->etage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank it seems to work ! How can I retrieve all apartments with sum of fractions of this apartment ?

Comment: For directly access to `fractions` from `apartment` i have added a new `hasManyThrough` relationship in `Lot` model and then load it. check it once

Comment: It doesn't find fractions from apartment :(

Comment: Ok it works ! It was just a problem with column name inside hasManyThrough

Comment: It works with count but how to retrieve sum of "surface_pondere" ?

Comment: in which table you have `surface_pondere` field ?

Comment: In fraction, I need to get sum of all fraction.surface_pondere for each lot

Comment: can you try `$apartment->fractions()->sum('surface_pondere');` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174358/discussion-between-rkj-and-furya).